# Remove columns outside the list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in pandas that has some columns that I don't need.
I would like to know if there is a way I can leverage just the columns I want and drop all the others before saving to the database.

Would it be possible to use a list and what is outside to be removed from the dataframe?

e.g.:

```
list_to_database = ['Name', 'Age', 'ZipCode', 'Email'..etc]

response = req.get(url)
json = response.json()
dt = pd.json_normalize(json, sep='_')

# if columns not in list drop
```

It's important that it be this way, because some data has more columns than others and as it is a very large query, it is necessary to predict that there will be new custom columns coming from api:

```
{
  user: 1,
  mame: "whatever",
  Age:....
  Zipcode: ...
  Email: ...
  ...

  customized: {
     child1: "may or may not",
     partner: "may or may not",
  },
  others: {
     scholarity: ....
  }

}
{
  user: 2,
  mame: "I don't know",
  Age:....
  Zipcode: ...
  Email: ...
  ...

  customized: {
     partner: "may or may not",
     parents: "may or may not",
  },
  others: {
     scholarity: ....
     student: Y/N
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [ask] and then try to produce a [mcve].

Comment: Aren't you looking for `df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop_list)`?

Comment: You could use your list to filter the columns you want with: `df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(list_to_database)]`

Comment: it's exactly the opposite @rpanai. thank's for comment

Comment: So @Rabinzel's comment is the solution you are looking for